# How to properly overwrite save method in custom User Profile Creation Form?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to overwrite `save` method for custom creation form in Django. I have model `UserProfile` which has many attributes. I've created a `UserProfileCreationForm` which should create and save both `User` and `UserProfile`. Now, it saves `User` but it can't save `UserProfile` (I've overwritten attribute `date_of_birth` to be able to choose instead of write date into charfield).

So what I want is to make this form save both `User` and `UserProfile` or raise error when I do `UserProfileCreationForm_object.save()`

Here is my form:

```
class UserProfileCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label="Username",max_length=40)
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Email address", max_length=40)
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First name', max_length=40)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last name', max_length=40)
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(label='Date of birth',
                                    widget=SelectDateWidget(years=[y for y in range(1930,2050)]),
                                    required=False)
    password1 = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label="Password confirmation", widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta():
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('username','email','first_name','last_name','password1','password2','date_of_birth','telephone','IBAN',)

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            msg = "Passwords don't match"
            raise forms.ValidationError("Password mismatch")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = User(username=self.cleaned_data['username'],
                    first_name=self.cleaned_data['first_name'],
                    last_name=self.cleaned_data['last_name'],
                    email=self.cleaned_data['email'])
        user.save()
        # user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        user_profile = super(self).save()
        if commit:
            user.save()
            user_profile.save()
        return user
```

In case it is necessary, here is the model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # ATRIBUTY KTORE BUDE MAT KAZDY
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_profile')
    iban = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True,verbose_name='IBAN')
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)

    HOW_DO_YOU_KNOW_ABOUT_US_CHOICES = (
        ('coincidence', u'It was coincidence'),
        ('relative_or_friends', 'From my relatives or friends'),
    )
    how_do_you_know_about_us = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=HOW_DO_YOU_KNOW_ABOUT_US_CHOICES, null=True,
                                                blank=True)

    MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('single', 'Single'),
        ('married', 'Married'),
        ('separated', 'Separated'),
        ('divorced', 'Divorced'),
        ('widowed', 'Widowed'),
    )
    marital_status = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)

    # TRANSLATORs ATTRIBUTES

    # jobs = models.Model(Job)

    language_tuples = models.ManyToManyField(LanguageTuple)

    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    number_of_ratings = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to redifine some fields like `username`, `email`, etc...
Here is a complete example with a `save` ovride:

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #self.error_class = BsErrorList

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]

        try:
            User._default_manager.get(email__iexact=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return email
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            'A user with that email already exists',
            code='duplicate_email',
        )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]

        # Create user_profile here

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

Edit: This solution reuse django's `User` form to register a new `User` then you have to create your custom profile.